# Isolation level at the database level for IBM DB2 LUW

Tags: db2, db2-luw, db2-11.5

How do I determine the default isolation level for our 11.5 DB2 instance running on Linux?

I see there is a "special register" from [this IBM documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=registers-current-isolation), however I'm not a DB2 expert so I'm not sure where to look for that, or how to "see" values for "special" registers.

I also looked at [this](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=mpf-mon-get-connection-details-table-function-get-connection-metrics-as-xml-document), but I am having no luck understanding how to obtain the current isolation from that either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Db2 the isolation level is specified at the statement or package (=a precompiled group of statements) level, not at the database or instance level. If not explicitly specified as part of a statement (`...WITH <isolation level`) or via the register that you have discovered, or by other means, it'll be `CS` (cursor stability). The behaviour of the CS level *is* controlled by the [database configuration parameter `cur_commit`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=parameters-cur-commit-currently-committed).

You can see the value of the `CURRENT ISOLATION` register by issuing `VALUES CURRENT ISOLATION`, and that will determine how the next statement in this session will be compiled/prepared. However, if you call a stored procedure in that same session, the statements in it might run with the isolation level specified (in effect) at the SP creation time.

You can see the isolation level for each statement in the package cache using [`MON_GET_PKG_CACHE_STMT()`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=mpf-mon-get-pkg-cache-stmt-table-function-get-package-cache-statement-metrics).

You can see the current isolation level of each in-flight transaction via [`MON_GET_UNIT_OF_WORK()`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=mpf-mon-get-unit-work-get-unit-work-metrics).

[Isolation levels](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=issues-isolation-levels).

Comment: cheers!  `VALUES CURRENT ISOLATION` returns a single value that is a zero-length string, so presumably `CS` since that's the default.

Comment: Not really; it'll be the value determined by the client session, and the default probably differs between the various clients. Not sure why is it your concern though. In Db2 normally it's the responsibility of the application to set whatever isolation level it needs, so you can be sure the application already does that, in one way or another.

Comment: We're migrating the data from DB2 into SQL Server, and attempting to configure the target database with the closest isolation level we can.  I'm expecting that the closest isolation level to CS is [RCSI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-set-options?view=sql-server-ver16#read_committed_snapshot--on--off-).  In my attempt to write a concise question, I may have fallen into the XY problem trap.

Comment: It might be somewhat equivalent _if_ on the Db2 side `cur_commit` is ON. Expect surprises in any case.